# Getting OpenAL to work in c++

Tags: c++, windows, openal

Hey guys I've been having trouble trying to get openAL to work in my c++ program. I've installed [oalinst](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx) and [ALUT](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/openal/Downloads/ALUT&FolderCTID=&View=%7B6A9700C6-7248-4CD2-83F5-268F2C176072%7D) (Windows Binary) but when I try to compile/run my program (using Qt Creator) I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\al\alut.h:5: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'alc.h': No such file or directory
```

I'm including "al/alut.h" in my main.cpp file, which try's to include both "alc.h" and "al.h"

I've tryed to search my entire computer for both of these header files and neither of them could be located (search began at "C:\" so I know it had to look though my entire system). Im using Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit.

Has anyone else had problems with the installers or binarys not installing/coming with these files? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken.  alc.h and others are bundled in the OpenAl SDK (which you'll need to add to your project's include and lib path).

http://connect.creativelabs.com/developer/Wiki/OpenAL%20SDK%20for%20Windows.aspx

Note: Right now, I can't download it from that source for some reason.

Comment: The website's been down for years now, so the original OpenAL is pretty much unobtainable. If you want to use OpenAL, you have to use OpenALSoft instead. But other than that, yes you are right.